# Range out of order in character class at RegExp

Tags: regex, angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to validate the email input filed using the expression `^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$` but it throws the error  `Range out of order in character class at RegExp` . How do i validate using that expression

```
 ngOnInit() {
    // created FormGroup using FormBuilder
    this.courseForm = this.fb.group({
      username: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$')]],
      email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$')]],
      address: (null),
      select: (null)
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

The error is due to the fact that a single `\` is removed and a part of your character class looks like `[_-.]`. It is an invalid range.

The pattern must be written as

```
'^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$'
```

That is:

- Double escape the `\` symbols
- Move `-` to the end of the character class to avoid having to escape it
- NOTE: You may also omit `^` and `$` as the pattern is wrapped with `^` and `$` automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Use patterns like this,

```
Validators.pattern(/^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$/) // wrapping the pattern within '/' and '/' (treating as RegExps) instead of treating it as strings
```

Comment: I was having the error on typescript and couldn't find where to slash. Wrapping like the answer fixed my whole problem. Thanks.